# Using reselect-selectors in a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

Let's say there is a `tree` in the state of my react-redux app and `tree` belongs to `myReducer`. In many cases I need this tree flattened, so I've got a selector:

```
const getTree = state => state.myReducer.tree;

export const getFlatNodes = createSelector(
    [getTree],
    (tree) => flattenTree(tree)
);
```

And now I need to access the flattened tree in an action

```
import { getFlatNodes } from 'path/to/selectors';

function myReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
       case SOME_ACTION:
           const flattenedTree = getFlatNodes(state);
           return {
               ...state,
               smth: getSmthFromFlattenedTree(flattenedTree)
           };
    }
}
```

This code will not work as expected since `state` in the reducer is just a slice of the app state. A simple workaround I came up with is to wrap `state` to make the passed parameter compatible:

```
import { getFlatNodes as _getFlatNodes } from 'path/to/selectors';
const getFlatNodes = myReducer => _getFlatNodes({ myReducer });
```

The code works, although it looks quite hacky and I'm not sure if it won't cause any issues.

Does anybody have any idea why and how it can be done better or my approach is good enough already?

Comment: You can try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/combine-section-reducers . With secion reducer you have access to entire state in each subreducer

Comment: It is common to use action payload to transfer the relevant data into the reducer. In your case, the component that calls the action or the action creator itself would use the selector to get the data from state with `getSmthFromFlattenedTree(flattenedTree)` and dispatch the action with payload: `{type: "SOME_ACTION", smthFromState}`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you make that in your action

```
const someAction = () => (dispatch, getState) => ({
  type: 'SOME_ACTION',
  payload: getFlatNodes(getState())
  // payload: getSmthFromFlattenedTree(getFlatNodes(getState()))
});
```

then in your reducer

```
function myReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
       case SOME_ACTION:
           return {
               ...state,
               smth: getSmthFromFlattenedTree(action.payload)
           };
    }
}
```